# Windows Spooler Events API doesn't generate events for network printers

Tags: c++, windows, events, printing, monitor

#### the context

i use Spooler Events API to capture events generated by the spooler when a user prints a document ie.

```
FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification
FindNextPrinterChangeNotification
```

#### the problem

When I print a document on the network printers from my machine no events are captured by the monitor (uses the functions above)

#### Notice

Events ARE generated OK for local printers, only Network Printers are problematic!

Comment: Firewall is not an issue, but anonymous named pipes access is. Read more about named pipes auth. Server and client should be in the same AD domain or have excplicitly set access with 'net use' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162722.aspx):

> Note: In Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2) and later, the Internet Connection Firewall (ICF) blocks printer ports by default, but an exception for File and Print Sharing can be enabled. If a user makes a printer connection to another machine, and the exception is not enabled, then the user will not receive printer change notifications from the server. A machine admin will have to enable exception.